# 184 environment variables too many?

Tags: environment-variables, profile, qnx

I am trying to find the cause of some OS wonkiness, and am concerned about environment variables.

The software I have been handed puts an incredibly high amount of environment variables into the user's `.profile`.

When I type `set | wc` the result is **9571 bytes long!** There are 184 entries. To me, this seems inordinately large, but I don't have anything explicit to point at and say "this is wrong because xyz".

I see nothing in the [ulimit documentation](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/utilities/k/ksh.html#ulimit) that speaks about environment variable total size, but am concerned. I'm not worried about overall memory utilization (there's enough to do what I need), but I am worried about overrunning some internal limit and causing odd behavior in the OS (*probably not germane to the question I'm asking, but the "odd behavior" is that shared memory queues are not giving me back all the data I put in on the other end. I'm getting around 5% out*).

Every single script that starts up, every single shell that is run, and every single binary that runs gets a full, individual copy of the environment variables, and I think 9k is too big. **Should this be a worry, or am I concerned over nothing?**

I'm running on an embedded x86 QNX 6.4.1 Neutrino system with half a gig of RAM.

Comment: 500,000,000 - 9,571 = 499,990,429

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, absolutely. I was wondering if there was some sort of reserved space per process that was being overfilled, not concerned with overall memory usage.

Comment: I think goldilocks is dead on. One way to get a little perspective is to `cd` into a directory with a ton of of little files then do `( set -- * ; echo $# )`

Comment: `set` does not give you the size of the environment, it also includes shell variables (and functions as well in some shells). Run `env | wc -c` to see the size of the environment.

Comment: @Gilles You are correct, there is a difference there. I get 9364 bytes with `env`. Not a big one, but certainly more accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I type set | wc the result is 9571 bytes long!

Assuming you got that number correct, it is in fact quite *small*, probably because you are using QNX.  On a normal desktop system, it is much larger.  Here's what I get on fedora 20:

```
> set | wc --bytes
133195
```

133 kB.  I did not count the entries as many of them are sourced functions (`git` seems to install a lot of these), but I did skim them over and there doesn't seem to be anything untoward.   A few kB at most is from custom stuff by me.

> I am worried about overrunning some internal limit and causing odd behavior in the OS

I very much doubt this is possible because a lack of bounds checking there would indicate a very significant bug in the implementation -- preventing someone from just writing a long variable to inject data into memory has to have been a basic concern.  Beyond that, as you say, 9kB is nothing memory wise.  I would presume lookups on these are done with a hash table, so the number of entries would not impair performance.

Comment: Oh. Wow. 133kB is huge!! :-) Then again, I'm used to dealing with an embedded system. Interesting, my Win 7 box is at about 3.5kB. But, as you said, this should have been a fundamental concern. The thing that got me going on this is the shared memory issue mentioned above and a file descriptor numbering `24770` when `ulimit` was 1000 per process. I think I'll mark "lots of environment variables" off my list of potential problems. Thanks.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, what do you get when you run `env | wc -c` as Gilles suggests above. I'm just curious how big the difference is for you. Thanks.

Comment: `env | wc- c` = 3849. The difference is mostly function definitions; if I write `set` to a file and remove those, I'm left with ~4800 bytes. I have 70 `env` variables.  So you do have a significant set of variables (which may, or may not represent someone's poor design choices), but again, I can't see it being anything to worry about.  If there were an issue there, it would be a sort of "heartbleed" scale vulnerability.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the input. I think it is a poor design choice and have been lobbying to change it. We'll see if I ever win. :-)

Answer (score 5):

`set` reports not only environment variables but also shell variables and, on some shells, functions. Use `env | wc -c` to get the size of the environment.

The environment size is indirectly limited by the maximum size of the arguments to `execve` (which consist of the environment plus the command line arguments). You can get the applicable value of this limit with `getconf ARG_MAX`.

3849 bytes doesn't seem particularly high. POSIX says that the limit can be as low as 4096 bytes, but with 512MB of RAM, your system isn't low-end and is likely set up to allow a lot more. In any case, if that limit was hit, then `execve` would fail; this has nothing to do with shared memory queues.

Comment: Great advice. `getconf ARG_MAX` reveals 61440, way more than the 9364 bytes `env | wc` shows me using. I agree it shouldn't be related to shared memory queues nor file descriptors being weird. (Also, `umask` was not being applied to new files properly... It was weird.). It was just a suspicion that something was going very strange with the OS. Of course, it was a wrong suspicion. In fact, the QNX documentation says I'll get `E2BIG` when I try to `execve` something if the environment is too big. See http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/e/execve.html. Thanks again.