# Wildcard in PATH (environment variable)

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path

I have a bunch of apps installed locally in my home directory. In order for them to be globally available I add them to `PATH` in `.bashrc`:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/user/apps/app1/bin"
PATH="$PATH:/home/user/apps/app2/bin"
PATH="$PATH:/home/user/apps/appn/bin"
```

How can I set it up so that I don't have to add each new one? I'm trying this but it's not working:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/user/apps/*/bin"
```

*NOTE*: I'm aware I can add them with a loop, but I'm also concerned my `PATH` variable will become too large, I'm wondering if it is possible to wildcard it somehow.

Comment: Presumably they have unique names, in which case you could symlink them to a (e.g.) `/home/user/apps/all-apps/` directory and just add that one directory?

Comment: @JeffSchaller that's probably what I'll end up doing if wildcard is not possible, but is a little bit of extra work that I'd happily avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wildcards will not be expanded in `$PATH`, no. Per the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables), PATH is:

> A colon-separated list of **directories** in which the shell looks for commands

(my emphasis).

Coming from another direction, the [Command Search and Execution section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) of the manual says, in part:

> If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no slashes, Bash searches each element of $PATH for a **directory** containing an executable file by that name.

... (my emphasis) -- which makes no mention of any special processing done on the path elements, only that they are expected to be directories (as-is).

I'm not sure off-hand what the limit is for the size of a bash variable; I suspect it's available memory. PATH doesn't need to be exported, but many people do; if it is exported, it will need to fit along with other environment variables and arguments into `getconf ARG_MAX` (ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124422/117549). A large PATH directory should not induce too much of a performance overhead, since bash uses a hash table to remember locations of previously-found commands (per-session).

If you do hit a limit (visual or technical) with adding each individual application directory to your PATH, I would recommend adding one "symlink" directory to your PATH where you then link in the desired executables from the various applications.

Comment: `PATH` needs to be exported if you want child processes to see it. E.g. if want scripts to be able to find the stuff in `/home/user/apps/app1/bin`, too, or if you launch some other program from an editor, or from `less` etc. The default `$PATH` that Bash sets on my Debian looks to be `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.`, which works for most things, but it's not the same as what I've set in the shell's startup files. Also the `.` at the end is somewhat interesting.

Comment: @ilkkachu if that does what I think it does then what happens if there's a file called `cd` in your directory :P

Comment: @php_nub_qq, nothing much, since the `cd` builtin gets run first. And since `.` was last there, even if it was `ls`, it would be found in the dirs earlier in `PATH`. But if you mistype that as `lss` or `sl`, then the lookup would go to the end...

Answer (score 0):

I've used a few solutions for this:

### 1. Use `find` to dynamically generate `$PATH`

For this, I've used a couple similar but slightly modified approaches. Suppose you have the following structure:

```
~/apps
├── foo
│   └── bin
├── bar
│   └── bin
└── blah
```

We can...

##### a. add existing *apps/*/bin/* folders to `$PATH`

This will search for any *bin/* directories in *`$HOME`/apps/** and add them to the `$PATH` when your shell loads, skipping any directories which don't have a *bin/* sub-directory.

```bash
#.bashrc

bins=$(
    find "$HOME/apps/" -maxdepth 2 -type d -name 'bin' \
        | tr '\n' ':' \
        | sed 's/:$//'
)
export PATH="$bins:$PATH"
```

*Produces:*

```
/home/user/apps/foo/bin:/home/user/apps/bar/bin:...
```

##### b. add any *somedir/*/bin/* to `$PATH`

...regardless of whether or not each folder in *somedir/* actually has a *bin/* sub-directory in it. That means, for the above directory structure, even *apps/blah/bin* will be added to the `$PATH` -- even though it doesn't exist!

This is useful when one of your directories doesn't *currently* have a *bin/* sub-directory, but it very well could in the future, and you don't want to have to reload your shell for it to be added to your `$PATH` after you create it.

```bash
#.bashrc

bins=$(
    find "$HOME/apps/" -maxdepth 1 -type d \
        | sed 's_$_/bin_' \
        | tr '\n' ':' \
        | sed 's/:$//'
)
export PATH="$bins:$PATH"
```

*Produces:*

```
/home/user/apps/foo/bin:/home/user/apps/bar/bin:/home/user/apps/blah/bin:...
```

There's possibly a ridiculously negligible performance hit since command lookups will briefly try to look in directories that don't exist, and it *feels* bad adding non-existing directories to my `$PATH`, but convenience-wise this is my preferred option.

### 2. Use `stow` to generate symlinks to your executables

`stow` was created for exactly this purpose. I'm currently using this setup to store all of my dotfiles in a git repo and copy them to my home directory :)

If you have a directory structure like:

```
.
├── bar
│   └── bin
│       ├── bar-executable-1
│       └── bar-executable-2
├── bin
└── foo
    └── bin
        ├── foo-executable-1
        └── foo-executable-2
```

And you want all of the files in *bar/bin/** and *foo/bin/** to be linked to in *bin/*, you can run:

```
cd somedir
stow -v --restow --target bin/ --dir bar/ bin
stow -v --restow --target bin/ --dir foo/ bin
```

*note: I use `--restow` for pruning, as it'll delete any old symlinks first before re-creating new symlinks*

This generates:

```
somedir
├── bar
│   └── bin
│       ├── bar-executable-1
│       └── bar-executable-2
├── bin
│   ├── bar-executable-1 -> ../bar/bin/bar-executable-1
│   ├── bar-executable-2 -> ../bar/bin/bar-executable-2
│   ├── foo-executable-1 -> ../foo/bin/foo-executable-1
│   └── foo-executable-2 -> ../foo/bin/foo-executable-2
└── foo
    └── bin
        ├── foo-executable-1
        └── foo-executable-2
```

And then you can simply add *somedir/bin/* to your `PATH`

#### making `stow` a little easier to use

If

1. The only directory inside each *appN* directory is a single *bin/* directory *and*
2. You're okay with moving the compiled *bin/* directory outside of your *apps/* directory

then you can use a slightly easier `stow` command:

```
/home/user
├── Desktop
├── Documents
├── Pictures
├── Videos
├── apps
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── bin
│   │       ├── bar-executable-1
│   │       └── bar-executable-2
│   └── foo
│       └── bin
│           ├── foo-executable-1
│           └── foo-executable-2
└── bin
```

```bash
cd
stow -v --restow --target ./ --dir apps/ foo bar
```

This basically says *Look in the "apps" folder for "packages" named "foo" and "bar", and copy the entire contents of both of those packages to the current directory using symlinks*. So if all that you have in *apps/foo/* and *apps/bar/* is a single *bin/* folder, then this generates a single *bin/* folder in the current directory with links to all of the files in *apps/foo/bin/* and *apps/bar/bin/*.

If, however, you have lots of other files/folders in *apps/foo/* and *apps/bar/* besides just a single *bin/* directory, then it'll recreate all of those in your home folder as well, which is probably not desirable, and you should stick with the first `stow` example.

https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/html_node/Installing-Packages.html

Comment: (1) As long as you’re using `tr` to separate the directory names, if you have GNU `find`, it might be better to use `-print0` and then `tr '\0' ':'`. (2) Removing the colon at the end of the dynamic part and then re-inserting it seems like a wasted effort. Worse, if the `find` doesn’t find anything, you will have prepended a colon to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

While adding `/home/user/apps/*/bin` to `$PATH` means search executables in a directory whose path is `/home/user/apps/*/bin` (a perfectly valid path, there's nothing that prevents the `*` character¹ from being used in the name of a file or directory on Unix), you can add the directories whose path matches `/home/user/apps/*/bin` at the time of writing using:

```
path+=( /home/user/apps/*/bin(N-/) )
```

In zsh, where the `$PATH` variable is tied to `$path` array like in csh, and the `-/` glob qualifier can be used to limit the expansion to files of type directory (or symlink to directory), and `N` for nullglob

You can also issue a `typeset -U path` to remove duplicates (`U` for unique).

In `fish`, where `$PATH` is exposed as an array and a nullglob-like behaviour is applied for globs used in `set`:

```
set PATH $PATH /home/user/apps/*/bin
```

(not restricting to files of type *directory* though).

POSIXly, you can always do:

```
for dir in /home/user/apps/*/bin; do
  [ -d "$dir" ] && PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}$dir"
done
```

In any case, if more directories are added to /home/user/apps/ later, they won't automagically appear in `$PATH`.

In ksh93, you could use disciplines for that magic to happen:

```
function PATH.get {
  typeset dir
  for dir in ~(N)/home/user/apps/*/bin; do
    [[ :$PATH: = *:"$dir":* || ! -d $dir ]] || PATH=${PATH:+$PATH:}$dir
  done
}
```

Where the value of `$PATH` is computed every time it's referenced.

In zsh, you could have it recomputed before each prompt using a `precmd()` hook, or with `bash` using `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

---

<sup>¹ or any character other than `/` and NUL or even non-characters for that matters.</sup>